# C# .NET DocX Librairy : resize an image

Tags: c#, .net, docx, novacode-docx

I havent found anything in this librairy to resize an image. In the object Novacode.Image there is very few methods / properties and none of them seem to be usefull to resize an image.

If anyone has a clue on how to do it, it will be very usefull

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, actually you cant resize the Novacode.Image object **BUT** you can do this :

```
DocX document = DocX.Load("D:\\Template.docx");
Novacode.Image drawing = document.AddImage(@"\images\img.png");
Picture pic = drawing.CreatePicture();
pic.Height = 340;
pic.Width = 310;
document.Paragraphs[0].InsertPicture(pic, 0);
document.SaveAs(@"docs\TemplateCompleted.docx");
```